# Interpolating Missing Data with Javascript-surface-plot

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d

I have started using Javascript-surface-plot to make 3D surface on the client side.  I fill google.visualization.DataTable with (x,y,z) values that I have available.  I cannot assign a z value to every (x,y) coordinate since there are none available.  As a consequence, instead of have a smooth surface, I have spikes where the data is assigned and the plot is zero elsewhere.

Is there a way to use Javascript-surface-plot to interpolate among the non-zero elements (or better still, form a Bezier surface)?  If not, is there a JavaScript-based 3D surface plotting program that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in support for interpolation. I will keep this in mind, though and try to implement it at some point. In the meantime, you could apply [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) to your input matrix and this should smooth out the surface.